# Amazon MWS API integration with R : SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: r, amazon-mws

Using this code (I have removed the ID and keys for security issues - they are correctly entered). I am not sure what's going wrong. Please help.

I am using R and trying to call RequestReport API (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html). So please suggest a solution in R script only.

```
base.html.string <- "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Reports/2009-01-01?"
SellerID <- 'xxxxxxxx'
MarketplaceID <- 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWSAccessKeyId <- 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWSsecretkey <- 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
ActionType <- 'RequestReport'
version.request <- '2009-01-01'
ReportType <- '_GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA_'
pb.txt <- Sys.time()
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz = Sys.timezone)
Timestamp <- strtrim(format(pb.date, tz = "GMT", usetz = FALSE, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"), 24)
str = paste('POST\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/\n',
            'AWSAccessKeyId=', AWSAccessKeyId,
            '&Action=', ActionType,
            '&Merchant=', SellerID,
            '&ReportType=', ReportType,
            '&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256',
            '&SignatureVersion=2',
            '&Timestamp=', gsub('%2E','.',gsub('%2D', '-', curlEscape(Timestamp))),
            '&Version=', version.request,
            sep = '')
Signature <- curlEscape(base64(hmac(enc2utf8(AWSsecretkey), enc2utf8(str), algo = 'sha256', serialize = FALSE,  raw = TRUE)))
AmazonURL <- paste(base.html.string,
                   'AWSAccessKeyId=', AWSAccessKeyId,
                   '&Action=', ActionType,
                   '&Merchant=', SellerID,
                   '&SignatureVersion=2',
                   '&Timestamp=', gsub('%2E','.',gsub('%2D', '-', curlEscape(Timestamp))),
                   '&Version=', version.request,
                   '&Signature=', Signature,
                   '&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256',
                   '&ReportType=', ReportType, 
                   sep = '')
AmazonResult <- getURL(AmazonURL)
AmazonResult
```

This is the response I get

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<ErrorResponse xmlns=\"http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/\">\n  <Error>\n    <Type>Sender</Type>\n    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>\n    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>\n  </Error>\n  <RequestID>fa1f2abf-3acf-435b-b98d-7377e778f53c</RequestID>\n</ErrorResponse>\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Rookie mistake. I used getURL(url) instead of using POST(url).

Secondly, the base.html.string is "https://mws.amazonservices.com/?" instead of "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Reports/2009-01-01?"